# C#- Check if a string has only the allowed character in it?

Tags: c#

Lets say I have some string like below

```
string x="Demo";
string x1="Demo/Abc";
```

So,my string may or may not contain  '/'.

So I want to create a method that accepts the string and returns false if it contains any special characters except '/'.

```
bool res= CheckCharacter(string input);
```

How to do this using c#?

Comment: What do you mean by `any special characters except '/'` exactly? You mean any other non-char character expect `/`?

Comment: use a Regular Expression

Comment: The string should not contain any special characters. Only '/' is allowed. The method should return true if it does not contain any special characters and may or not contain '/'.

Comment: What you have tried so far ?

Comment: You need a good book or tutorial on C#. That last piece of code shows you still need to learn the basics.

Comment: What are _special characters_? Or in other words: what are allowed characters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regular expressions are probably the best bet here. Your function would be:

```
public bool CheckChar(string input)
{
    return Regex.IsMatch(input, @"^[a-zA-Z0-9/]+$");
}
```

This should work for your needs if not I would suggest using https://regexr.com/ to build and test another.

Comment: If I pass '\' it returns true. But expected is it should return false.

Comment: @Codexer Care to elaborate?

Comment: I have re-edited to be corrected as @41686d6564 was correct

Comment: @Codexer That doesn't mean you should roll back an edit that fixes the code. Please read the "Editing Code in Answers" section in [this FAQ post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260246/8967612).

Comment: @Codexer Your quoted text is from the "Editing Code in **Questions**" section. Fixing code mistakes in answers _is_ advised, especially when the original intent is obvious.

Answer (score 4):

Presuming accepted characters are letters, digits and `/`, you could use:

```
public static bool CheckCharacter(string input)
    => input?.All(c => c == '/' || char.IsLetterOrDigit(c)) == true;
```

Comment: TBH, this is better (more understandable) than the RegEx answer.  Any time someone suggests RegEx as an answer, should be ignored :-)

Comment: @Neil I would agree in this case. The regex answer assumes the OP knows `Regex` and how it works, this may not be the case. In my opinion it should have been closed as the OP didn't show any attempt to solve their requirement and it lacked context; this was a handout.